# How to stop HREF truncation in HTML

Tags: python, html

Recently been trying to parse certain data values from Python into the hash of a hyperlink like so:

```
'<a href="mysite.com/page#name=' +str(value1)+ '&pass=' +str(value2)+ '">Link</a>'
```

This gets passed to the site via `Flask` and put into a table generated by a Panda's DataFrame as an entry. When inspecting element, it seems to actually parse the values, but the href gets truncated in the middle of the hash like so:

```
<a href="mysite.com/page#name=value1&pass=val...
```

This then causes any code beneath this link to be pulled into the `href`, ruining the formatting of the rest of the page, until it finds another `"`. I have checked many times, and in the links I have put the ending double-quote, but it is in the part of the code that gets truncated. Any helpful tips as to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Panda is truncating the output for displaying purpose.
The default `max_colwidth` is 50. You can set this value yourself like this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

`-1` here basically turns off the truncating.

Comment: Didn't think it was that bad of a question to get down voted. 

Jokes aside, this change made the link work as intended. Thanks!

Comment: No it was not a bad question I did not downvote it! I'm happy that helped.

Comment: I know. I just thought that putting a 'minus one' in ``` auto-down voted. Though I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh I see! Happy coding mate. If that resolved your issue please check my answer as the accepted one. Happy coding